# combine Join and not in date query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are my 2 tables.
Review_master

```
id Rev_month Rev_year ...
1  JAN       2017
2  MAR       2017
4  FEB       2017
```

Review_det

```
Id Rev_id closed_date (MM/DD/YYYY)
1   1      01/01/2017
2   1      02/01/2017
3   1      01/17/2017
4   2      03/03/2017
5   2      04/03/2017
6   4      02/02/2017
6   4      02/05/2017
```

Now i need to find out number of reviews which are closed outside that month. Review id "1" is of Jan month, and from review details table review_detail_id 2 is closed on feb month, so it should be counted.
Final output:

```
Rev_Id #_Closed_outside_month
1       1
2       1
4       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there two main points :

1. Inequality of literal value of `MON` for `closed date` and `rev_month`

   ```
    rev_month != to_char(closed_date,'MON')
   ```
2. Combining two tables with `outer join`.

So, you can easily use the following :

```
select m.id "Rev_id", count(closed_date) "#_Closed_outside_month"
  from Review_det d right outer join Review_master m on ( d.Rev_id = m.id )
    and rev_month != to_char(closed_date,'MON')
 group by m.id
 order by m.id;
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/914298/17)

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Added rev_year to the ON condition, to make sure it works for 2016 and 2017.. and worked.

Comment: @Pat Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with review_master (id, rev_month, rev_year) as
  2  (select 1, 'jan', '2017' from dual union
  3   select 2, 'mar', '2017' from dual union
  4   select 4, 'feb', '2017' from dual),
  5  review_det (id, rev_id, closed_date) as
  6  (select 1, 1, date '2017-01-01' from dual union
  7   select 2, 1, date '2017-02-01' from dual union
  8   select 3, 1, date '2017-01-17' from dual union
  9   select 4, 2, date '2017-03-03' from dual union
 10   select 5, 2, date '2017-04-03' from dual union
 11   select 6, 4, date '2017-02-02' from dual union
 12   select 7, 4, date '2017-02-05' from dual)
 13  select m.id,
 14    case when to_char(d.closed_date, 'mmyyyy') <>
 15              to_char(to_date(m.rev_month||' '||m.rev_year, 'mon yyyy',
 16                 'nls_date_language = english'), 'mmyyyy')
 17         then 1
 18         else 0
 19    end closed_outside_Month
 20  from review_master m, review_det d
 21  where m.id = d.rev_id
 22    and d.closed_date = (select max(d1.closed_date)
 23                         from review_Det d1
 24                         where d1.rev_id = d.rev_id
 25                        );

        ID CLOSED_OUTSIDE_MONTH
---------- --------------------
         1                    1
         2                    1
         4                    0

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, not sure is it working, but it is not grouping and counting the one's not in that month. It is printing always 1 and 0.

Comment: Well, that's query based on how I understood your question, looking at sample data you posted. Sorry if I got it wrong (obviously, I did).